# Async scan of database table

Tags: java, caching, jdbc, asynchronous, traversal

I want to traverse all rows of a DB table from my java code. 
Here i am looking for the best solution.

The solution i have in my mind is to buffer something like 100k rows and refill the buffer when at least 80% of buffer is consumed asynchronously.
Thus there would be a circular linked list of size 100k. There would be a thread when invokes adds 80,000 feeds to the link list. Whenever 80% of 100k is consumed , this thread is invoked and it loads the next 80k feeds to the linked list over writing the previous consumed rows.

Is there any similar library in java which does the same to a DB table ?

Comment: Would do you mean with '1 lack'?

Comment: 100000 number , 1 L or 1 lakh  , sorry about the typo

Comment: lakh is not English: it has no meaning outside of south Asia (India and surrounding countries)